# ActionView::Template::Error: unexpected token at '{{2+2}}'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, phantomjs, capybara-webkit

I'm having trouble integrating JS tests into my rails/angular application. In particular, my test setup is choking on the 8th and final occurrence of {{handlebars}} in this html file, and I cant' figure out what's special about this occurrence.

The problem error comes at line 784 of [_form.html.erb](https://github.com/dcmorse/contra/blob/fb3103ab22d662055a6130ff4f3d0ec0ccf9c6ed/app/views/dances/_form.html.erb):

```
<textarea class="figures_json col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-xs-9" readonly="readonly" name="dance[figures_json]" id="dance_figures_json">
{{2+2}}</textarea>
```

And the error is this:

```
dm@red:~/contra$ rspec ./spec/features/dances/create_spec.rb:7 
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/features/dances/create_spec.rb"=>[7]}}
F

Failures:

  1) Creating dances creates a new dance with non-javascript data
     Failure/Error: JSON.parse figures_json

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       784: unexpected token at '{{2+2}}'
     # ./app/models/dance.rb:10:in `figures'
     # ./app/views/dances/_bodyshow.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_dances__bodyshow_html_erb__2235413439078114529_46217560'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
     # ./app/views/dances/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_dances_show_html_erb__1493296941766923553_47454680'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:43:in `call'
     # /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
     #   expected to find css "h1" with text "Call Me" but there were no matches. Also found "Internal Server Error", which matched the selector but not all filters.
     #   /home/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:128:in `block in assert_selector'

Finished in 1.77 seconds (files took 1.59 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/dances/create_spec.rb:7 # Creating dances creates a new dance with non-javascript data
```

Here's a link to my [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/dcmorse/contra/blob/fb3103ab22d662055a6130ff4f3d0ec0ccf9c6ed/Gemfile.lock) so you can see what versions of stuff I'm using.

Comment: can you post the code in `create_spec.rb` related to the error?

Comment: Did you try to test it manually in browser to see if it throws the same error?

Comment: Your problem is that `figures_json` is `undefined` then `JSON.parse(undefined)` = fail.

Comment: @ArunKumar the create_spec.rb is here https://github.com/dcmorse/contra/blob/fb3103ab22d662055a6130ff4f3d0ec0ccf9c6ed/spec/features/dances/create_spec.rb

Comment: @MarkoKacanski yes it works in the browser.

Comment: Correction@ArunKumar, create_speck.rb is here: https://github.com/dcmorse/contra/blob/fb3103ab22d662055a6130ff4f3d0ec0ccf9c6ed/spec/features/dances/create_spec.rb

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that problem comes from line 784 of `_form.html.erb`? I can't find this file in a call stack! Call stack states it chokes on [dance.rb#10](https://github.com/dcmorse/contra/blob/fb3103ab22d662055a6130ff4f3d0ec0ccf9c6ed/app/models/dance.rb#L10) and, probably, `figures_json` contains that `{{2+2}}` which is not a JSON.

**UPDATE**

I just had a spare minute to download & look what is actually happening in the app.
When you render `new` action you, actually, send the `create` action via JS and create the `Dance` with value `{{2+2}}` from that `_form`. While it looks odd to me (why create on just `new` action?) I figure out the reason – angular does not evaluate expressions inside `textarea`, you need to bind it to `ng-model`. So, you want to re-write that textarea as this:

```
<textarea class="figures_json col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-xs-9" readonly="readonly" name="dance[figures_json]" id="dance_figures_json" ng-model="2+2">
```

Comment: `{{2+2}}` is not a JSON. `{{2+2}}` is an angular expression that should evaluate to "4". It's inserted as proof that angular is not working properly.

Comment: Here's direct evidence that Angular tries to support mustaches in textarea. Also, it works in development. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea

Comment: I read the doc and did not find any evidence that it supports mustache; in fact it states that data-binding is just the same as for inputs, and inputs require you to use `ng-model`. I think it does not relate to dev mode, but to the browser. Why don't use documented `ng-model`?

Comment: I'll try using ng-model.

Comment: So the reason I wanna use mustaches instead of ng-value, is that I need to transform the model in basically read-only way. I believe ng-values have to be 'lvalues' - both readable by evaluating them, and writeable by placing them to the left hand side of an '='s sign. 

So I say {{2+2}} should eval to "4" as a metaphor for {{some_fancy_function(object)}} should evalute to "some fancy string".